# Put "all locales" screenshot before locale specific screenshot

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

My extension has 4 locale specific screenshots and one "all locales" video. I ordered the video as first (in the developer dashboard) and yet when I visit my extension's page in Chrome Web Store the video shown last. Is it intended behavior or bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Based from the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images?hl=itdocumentation), when you edit your app's listing, mousing over a screenshot's thumbnail brings up controls that let you delete the screenshot or change its position. Try to set the position of the video to every locale of your item. If this is not working, you can file a [bug](http://crbug.com/) here.

Comment: The video positioned first in every locale but it's still shown last in CWS. If I set video to en locale it's shown first, but If I try to link to the same video in other locale and set it to that locale the video gets removed from en locale.